# Get menu links only

Tags: menus, html5

I'm creating a template in HTML5. On navigatiom menu i need to implement something like this

```
<nav>
 <a href="url1">url1</a>
 <a href="url1">url2</a>
 <a href="url1">url3</a>
 <a href="url1">url4</a>
 ...
 <a href="urln">urln</a>
</nav>
```

If i use 'wp_nav_menu', it prints

```
<div><ul><li><a>
```

when i need just

```
<a>
```

There is a way to get that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom walker:

```
class WPSE_33175_Simple_Walker extends Walker
{
    public function walk( $elements, $max_depth )
    {
        $list = array ();

        foreach ( $elements as $item )
            $list[] = "<a href='$item->url'>$item->title</a>";

        return join( "\n", $list );
    }
}
```

… and then call `wp_nav_menu()` like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'theme_location' => 'your_registered_theme_location',
        'walker'         => new WPSE_33175_Simple_Walker,
        'items_wrap'     => '<nav>%3$s</nav>'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items