# How to add class and span to

Tags: menus, pages, page-template, navigation, design

First of all this is my first wordpress theme where im making

So i want to add class to `<a>` and `<span>` in navbar

and want to looks like this

```
<a class="menu_top" href="/feedback/"><span>Contact</span></a>
<a class="menu_top" href="/lastnews/"><span>News</span></a>
<a class="menu_top" href="/dmca/"><span>DMCA</span>
```

instead of this

```
<ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="/feedback/">Contact</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="/dmca/">DMCA</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="lastnews/">News</a></li></ul>
```

Thats i do is to get rid of `<li>` using

```
<?php
$menuParameters = array(
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>
```

and curently i have code like this in my output:

```
<a href="/feedback/">Contact</a>
<a href="/dmca/">DMCA</a>
<a href="/lastnews/">News</a>
```

Waiting for your answers thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [How does a minimal menu walker look like?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112442/73) That would be fastest and most simple solution.

Comment: yes i have try to make like 3 times walker but cant get to work, its still confused

Comment: You can just _copy_ my example and add your class attribute.